# COM object that has been separated from its underlying RCW cannot be used?

Tags: c#, ms-access

Setting aside the salt and hash debate. And Please reply only if you know the answer.

I am trying to create a method where a user enters their credentials with date and times are recorded automatically when logging in and out.

I have two problems

Problem 1 - 
I have created a simple method just for logging in and out. When I included the date and time code I noted that these where recorded and stored for all users. I currently have two users. So if one user logins date and time are recorded and stamp for the other user.

Problem 2 - 
The second problem is as the subject headers says I get a error message when the Update command parameter is in the same method as with Select.

If anyone could help me I would be grateful with both of the problems. Hopefully It is only a minor issue? If omitting date and time then I will be grateful if someone could help me on multi login function.

Access 2003 ~ Two tables. Table 1 - Named LoginTable   Table 2 - Named LoginLogTable

LoginTable

> FieldName  DataType

```
UserName   Text
Password   Text

LoginLogTable
FieldName     DataType
UserNameID    Text
UserName      Text
LoggedIn      Date/Time
LoggedInTime  Date/Time     



 private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    using (var command = myCon.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = "select UserName, Password from LoginTable where WHERE STRCOMP(UserName, @UserName,0) = 0 AND STRCOMP(Password, @Password,0)=0";
           command.Parameters.AddWithValue("UserName", (txtUserName.Text));
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Password", (txtPassword.Text));
            myCon.Open();

            var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            {
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Login Successful");
                    Form2 frm = new Form2();
                    frm.Show();
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                      txtUserName.Text = reader["UserName"].ToString();
                      txtPassword.Text = reader["Password"].ToString();
                    }

                    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
                    cmd.Connection = myCon;

                     cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE [LoginLogTable] SET [LoggedInDate] = ?, [LoggedInTime] = ?";
                      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LoggedInDate", DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LoggedInTime", DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm"));
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    myCon.Close();

                }
            else MessageBox.Show("Login Falied");
            }

        }
           myCon.Close();
           myCon.Close();
```

}

Comment: out of curiosity, why are you closing the connection 3 times?

Comment: @M Patel it should be closing twice? shouldn't? I am looking at it now on opening and closing connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have any condition in your `update` query, so it will update all records in the table. Add a condition to only update a single record. I don't know what you have in your table, but something like this:

```
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE [LoginLogTable] SET [LoggedInDate] = ?, [LoggedInTime] = ? where UserName = ?";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("LoggedInDate", DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("LoggedInTime", DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm"));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("UserName", txtUserName.Text);
```

You should close and dispose the first data reader and command before executing the second command.

Comment: thank you. I had 2 opening connection and 3 closing connection, so that didn't make any sense. sorted that out. And as you pointed out I forgot to include where clause as well.

Comment: To add to this, I think you should also place you database connection between a 'using' statement. This will ensure that you connection is also closed and disposed without you having to explicitly call Close() on it.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you need a UserName column in your LoginLogTable and update table something like this

```
UPDATE [LoginLogTable] SET [LoggedInDate] = ?, [LoggedInTime] = ? WHERE UserName = 'YourUserName'.
```

And the second, I believe you no need a Reader here. You can use [ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) instead Reader. The second command can not run because a Reader has open state.